# creating new kendo widget

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need to create a new kendo widget. I searched for documentation but very less documentation is present. I am not clear with the steps needed to create new widget. Could anybody provide steps to create new kendo widget. I am very new to kendo.

I need to create html template and show it in kendo grid. The properties of html template should change according to the value in column for that particular row.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/create-custom-kendo-widget

Comment: I have checked this URL. This URL does not provide very basic information like where (in which file) to put which code. I am beginner to kendo so unable to workout with it. Is there any other documentation which provides more detailed information?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/creating-custom-kendo-ui-plugins with source code available here: https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-plugins